# VKAPI Error 29 - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь использовать VKAPI для NodeJS. Но при пером же hello world'е от VKAPI, которая предоставлена у них на гитхабе:

```
const VkBot = require('node-vk-bot-api');

const bot = new VkBot("dfk2k0 ************** dk3o023d");

bot.command('/start', (ctx) => {
  ctx.reply('Hello!');
});
bot.startPolling((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
ApiError: ApiError
    at VkBot.module.exports (O:\Projects\Bot\node_modules\node-vk-bot-api\lib\api.js:12:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async VkBot.module.exports (O:\Projects\Bot\node_modules\node-vk-bot-api\lib\methods\getLongPollParams.js:10:24)
    at async VkBot.module.exports (O:\Projects\Bot\node_modules\node-vk-bot-api\lib\methods\startPolling.js:11:29) {
  response: {
    error_code: 29,
    error_msg: 'Rate limit reached',
    request_params: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}
```

Есть какой нибуть выход их такой ситуации? А то других helloworld'ов для VKAPI я не нашел.

Comment: Зачем, а главное н#@1я юзать готовые библиотеки для API, карл, тебе сложно отправить get запрос, благо у ВК удобное апи в этом плане

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer ну если есть Api для NodeJS, че бы не воспользоваться?

Comment: как минимум, отправить апи запрос - дело минуты, а изучать абсолютно непонятную библиотеку - да, вот это каеф